# Dynamically loaded external local script not running

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load an external local script from a local html page.

```
folder
    index.html
    index.js
    scripts
        external.js
```

**index.html**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js" ></script>
```

**index.js**

```js
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'scripts/external.js';
document.currentScript.insertBefore(script, document.currentScript);
script.addEventListener('load', e => {console.log(foo);});
```

**external.js**

```js
const foo = 'foo';
```

When I run index.html, no error is thrown but the event listener is not called. Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. When I run it, this error is thrown: *Uncaught DOMException: Node.insertBefore: Child to insert before is not a child of this node*

Comment: Adding `parentNode` causes it to work in my tests.

Comment: Using `document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore` fixed the issue